# Automatically change database row item if it has not been changed within a certain time

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time on creating a time allowance for reservations in PHP. I did research regarding this but unfortunately I do not know what are the exact terms for this.

I already have a working reservation module, I need to add a feature that automatically cancels that reservation within 30 minutes if it is not confirmed by the client.

Is there a PHP code fragment where it will automatically set the value of a row if it has not been changed within 30 mins?

PS: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: use a cron to update the record

Comment: Any reason for downvote? Anyways, I'll try that @urfusion.

Comment: I didn't down vote pal.

Comment: You can use cron as well as make simple function with ajax and call that function using setTimeout function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a PHP code fragment where it will automatically set the value of a row if it has not been changed within 30 mins?

No.  This is data-centric, presumably your "reservation" is stored in a database (e.g. MySQL)?

PHP as a platform is in 99.9% of scenarios responding to a request (either CLI or HTTP) - or so called "event driven".  There is no easy way to create an "event" for something expiring in the future without moving your mind beyond pure PHP.

You can be [event driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) in your updating of an "updated at" field by using your DBMS' timestamp (e.g. see [`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)) from which you can check (on any future event) whether the record has "expired" (last updated timestamp + 30 minutes).

If you need to generate an event *when expiry occurs* (e.g. send an email to say the reservation was cancelled), unless you have some sort of 'deferred execution' (a feature of some queuing platforms - outside the scope of this answer) you will need to [periodically poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) (the "kind-of" opposite to event driven) to find any records which have expired.

The most common means of doing that through PHP on a LAMP stack is by writing a [`cronjob`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).  That's a forever-running service which will (with a maximum frequency of every 60 seconds) trigger your code.

If you're heading down the polling route but only need to manipulate date (no email sending etc), you could investigate using your DBMS scheduler (e.g. MySQL [`events`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)).  A word of warning though - hiding business logic inside the database doesn't always lead to maintainable solutions.

---

**Added note**: If you're not already using a PHP framework, consider discovering the joys of products like [`laravel`](https://laravel.com) which give you [`task scheduling`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) out of the box.

Comment: I see. I'm new to cron jobs and looks confusing. I'll try using timestamp instead. Thanks for this idea!

Comment: I'll check laravel too.

Comment: I'd really strongly recommend picking up a framework.  It'll abstract a lot of the confusion away for you :-)  Regarding `cronjobs` - all you need to understand is you're telling your server to run a command (e.g. `php myscript.php`) for some given interval (e.g. minutely, daily, or on 3pm every 2nd Wednesday).  That's all cron does - one thing, really well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach:

one of these 2 ways:
1) when checking open reservations, always add the check `WHERE createdat > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`.
that way you will only *see* the reservations that still can be confirmed
Note that 30 minutes is now hard coded in the query /queries

2) when the time can vary, you could also consider adding an extra column to you table: expiresat
When inserting your reservation, you can write the moment until the reservation will expire:
`INSERT INTO table (all, columns, expiresat) VALUES ('all', 'values', NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`
this way you could vary the number of minutes per order, or give people at night more time fi.

When confirming, you can reset the value of this column to null 
And you have to modify the queries with:
`WHERE expiresat > NOW() OR expirexat is null`

It is more effort in the programming side, but you do not have to worry about processes always having to run to remove open reservations